# Printing a mkdocs-generated html page exposes links

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

When I print an mkdocs-generated html page (using google chrome in this case) the page explicitly prints the relative paths underlying a page link. For example:

In mkdocs markdown file:

```
to read more, visit this [page](../../more_info_page).
```

On the resulting HTML page:

```
to read more, visit this page.
```

Printing the html page:

```
to read more, visit this page[../../more_info_page].
```

Is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: You don't mention which MkDocs theme you are using. It's possible the theme includes some [print specific CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/print-url-after-links/) which is causing this. Or it could be the browser's default behavior.

Comment: Good point. I'm using the 'Material' theme - I'll look into whether it may be using specific print css. Also, I tried printing across different browsers - same result. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the Material theme defines this rule for print: `@media print { .md-typeset a:after { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);  content: " [" attr(href) "]" } }`, which causes the URL to be displayed in brackets after the link text. You can see is defined in the [source code](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/6e43b874f6eaa9764b67a0902d0eae38bbb35f35/src/assets/stylesheets/base/_typeset.scss#L152-L161).

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. I can work with that. Thanks.